# Scope of the variables

Tags: javascript, scope

I do not understand why alert is `undefined` in this case:

```
var name = 'Alice';
function init() {
    var name = "Zara"; 
    function displayName() {
        var name = name;
        alert(name);
    }
    name = 'John';
    return displayName;    
}
var displayName = init();
name = 'Ben';
displayName();
```

As far as I understand the problem is with `var name = name`, but I do not know why function does not assign `name` from `init()` function.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `var name = name;` is assigning the inner `name` variable to itself; it's effectively `var name; name = name;` Since it starts out with the value `undefined`, `name = name` leaves it with the value `undefined`. See the linked question's answers for more details.

Answer (score -1):

name keyword is conflicting. So use this keyword.

```js
var name = 'Alice';
function init() 
{
    var name = "Zara"; 
    function displayName() {
        this.name = name;
        alert(name);
    }
    name = 'John';
    return displayName;    
}
var displayName = init();
name = 'Ben';
displayName();
```